# Separate environment variables for multiple services with same image

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, docker-image, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to [use two instances of the same image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#starting-multiple-services-from-the-same-image), more specifically [the `mysql` service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html). I can't figure out how to use different environment variables for each of the service instances:

```yaml
services:
  - name: mysql:8.0.32
    alias: maindb
  - name: mysql:8.0.32
    alias: otherdb

variables:
  # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_DATABASE
  MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
  MYSQL_USER: $DB_USERNAME
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
  MYSQL_HOST: $DB_HOST
  MYSQL_PORT: $DB_PORT
```

According to the docs, it is possible to [specify variables directly for the service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#available-settings-for-services), so I thought, I just need to do this:

```yaml
services:
  - name: mysql:8.0.32
    alias: maindb
    variables:
      # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_DATABASE
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USERNAME
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_HOST: $DB_HOST
      MYSQL_PORT: $DB_PORT
  - name: mysql:8.0.32
    alias: otherdb
    variables:
      # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB2_DATABASE
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB2_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_USER: $DB2_USERNAME
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB2_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_HOST: $DB2_HOST
      MYSQL_PORT: $DB2_PORT
```

but it warns you that

> ℹ️ Variables set in the GitLab UI are not passed down to the service containers. For more information, see [GitLab CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html).

So, maybe that explains this:

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-[...]-mysql-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
start service container: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-[...]-mysql-0 AS /runner-[...]-mysql-0-wait-for-service/service (services.go:187:0s)
Service container logs:
2023-11-09T10:03:01.238208088Z 2023-11-09 10:03:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
2023-11-09T10:03:01.390086193Z 2023-11-09 10:03:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-11-09T10:03:01.399340015Z 2023-11-09 10:03:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.32-1.el8 started.
2023-11-09T10:03:01.542018145Z 2023-11-09 10:03:01+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
2023-11-09T10:03:01.542054237Z     You need to specify one of the following as an environment variable:
2023-11-09T10:03:01.542058782Z     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
2023-11-09T10:03:01.542062323Z     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
2023-11-09T10:03:01.542065140Z     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

The docs are not clear on this or am I missing something?

Comment: yes the service (a seperate docker container) will not have access to your job's variables.
But you can directly overwrite e.g. `MYSQL_DATABASE` in jour job.

Comment: Please read my question again to the end. You'll see, that that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Overall I find running two or more services via gitlab-ci unreliable, and usually I fall into `docker-compose`, because it's much simpler to test locally. `but it warns you that` Who is "it"?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on GitLabs unreliability? What problems did you encounter? Unfortunately, I'm currently not using `docker-compose` locally, so that wouldn't make these environments more consistent in my case.

Comment: Where are you setting the variable values you're using? Can you just set the values directly instead of relying on variable expansion?

Comment: I set them via the variables setting GUI as described in the docs. So you want me to write passwords and such directly into the .gitlab-ci.yml? I mean, the above example worked just fine when it was just one service.

Comment: @shaedrich you can't set them by reference

Comment: Okay ... is there a reason for that? Seems buggy to me or at least inconsistent, then

Comment: @shaedrich is there a problem with writing it directly in the YAML? If security is your concern, the MySQL container is ephemeral and is only exposed to the job container... nothing except the job can even connect to it, even if they have the password, so I'm not sure I see any major issues just writing it in the YAML, or even just configuring MySQL to not require a password.

Comment: Yeah, I think, security is why the GUI variables were added in the first place aside from abstracting that. You are right, it's just a temporal testing environment. But there's a reason, we don't write these information in plain text in a YAML file rather than neatly over the GUI. Okay, but assuming one actually prefers mixing configuration with definition, shouldn't both variants work? Anyway, I'll gonna give your approach a try since that seems to be the only way to make that work apparently 